# MATLAB Add 1's to matrix elements around a specific element

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Using MATLAB, I have a matrix such as:

```
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

The aim is to represent the zero's as a mine in a minesweeper program and the values around the 0's should reflect how many mines are adjacent to it.

Therefore creating a vector like this:

```
1 2 0 
1 0 2
1 1 1
```

I have thought to take elements around the zero as a sub matrix and then add 1, but then it will turn 0's into 1's.

How would I program such a task?

Comment: What output do you want for `[1 1 0;1 1 1;1 0 1]`? Do you want `[0 1 0;1 2 2;1 0 1]`? Would this turn the 1,1 element into a mine?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer which suits you the best by clicking the checkmark on the right hand side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be achieved by simple convolution plus some post-processing on the resultant matrix as follows:

```
% Defining a 6x6 matrix of zeros and ones

mineMat=randi(2,6,6)-1;
numberOfMines=conv2(double(~mineMat),ones(3,3),'same').*mineMat;

% Result:

mineMat=

 1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0     1
 0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     0

numberOfMines=

 3     0     3     3     0     0
 0     0     0     3     0     0
 2     3     2     3     4     0
 1     2     2     4     0     4
 0     3     0     0     0     0
 0     3     3     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

[Parag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26112273/2586922) would be my first option. Another approach is to use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html) (Image Processing Toolbox):

```
blockproc(~M, [1 1], @(x)sum(x.data(:)), 'Bordersize', [1 1], 'TrimBorder', 0).*M
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to apply a (two dimensional) filter:

```
M = [1 1 0; 1 0 1; 1 1 1]==0;

F = filter2(ones(3),M);
F(M)=0
```

The middle line basically does the work (applying the filter) to create the count. The last line ensures that the mines stay at value 0.